# File IO inside CasperJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, casperjs

Is it possible do read/write files inside a CasperJS Script ?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.readFileSync('testdata.data', 'utf-8');
console.log(data);
```

Calling `casperjs fileio.js`returns:

```
'undefined' is not a function
```

Even after running `npm install fs`.

Bonus point if not : explain why ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

CasperJS does not make use of NodeJS' `fs` module. Instead, it uses that of [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/)

Here's a short example of how to use PhantomJS' filesystem module:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var utils = require('utils');
var data = fs.read('testdata.dat');
utils.dump(data);
```

Comment: Found this answer after hours of frustration - Doh! Anyone know why they use separate node modules or couldn't have consistent naming for the few functions they have? It seems very very counter-intuitive and has caused other developers much frustration as well.

Comment: @Zaheer Casperjs is a Qt implementation, not a nodejs library or similar, so they had to reinvent the wheel